# Concrete5 - Why is my block controller set() not working?

Tags: concrete5

I have a custom block which has a default view with a form in it. When that form is submitted I set a controller flag and the block is (should be) updated to display more information.

The problem is my view is treating it like I have no data/variables set

**Controller.php**

```
public $unlocked = false;
public $employer;
public $shortname = "not loaded";

public function on_page_view() { //already overridden because I'm compiling LESS
    ...
    $this->setViewVariables(); 
}

function setViewVariables() {
    $this->set('shortname', $this->shortname);
    $this->set('is_unlocked', $this->unlocked);
    ...
}

public function action_accesscode_unlock() {
    $this->unlocked = true;
    $this->shortname = "fred";
    //Have also tried calling $this->setViewVariables(); as well, 
    //before I realised view() and on_page_view() were called after this anyway
}
```

**View.php**

```
<?php if ( !$is_unlocked ) { 
    echo $shortname; //does correctly display the default value
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->action('accesscode_unlock')?>" id="accessform" method="post">
        ...
    </form>

<?php } else {

     //THIS section is never displayed (always reloads form with default name)
     echo $shortname;

} ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here so that the new variable values are never set in the view?

**Edit**

After replying to JohnTheFish I just realised, the LESS compilation code I use includes the following lines (used to get block path). Could this be changing the instance used for different parts of the lifecycle?

```
$bv = new BlockView();
$bv->setController($this);
$bv->setBlockObject($this->getBlockObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on_page_view runs before action_accesscode_unlock, so the logic of action_accesscode_unlock does not happen until after the variables are set.

You could try adding a call to setViewVariables to the end of action_accesscode_unlock.

(In answer to your edit, yes, it could)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case - if I call setViewVariables from only action_accesscode_unlock the view gets updated correctly (but obviously I dont get any variables before submission) ... If I add setViewVariables to on_page_view or view as well as the action, then the view doesnt update, it seems that view/on_page_update is called after and overrides things. Also if I log and increment a member variable in each place I call setViewVariables the value is always reset to 1 (doesnt count up) which makes me think different instances

Comment: Is $this->unlocked also in the block data xml? Perhaps an empty value is being pulled in from the database.

Comment: Nothing was in the db table yet, I work backwards from design -> controller -> db -> edit, I'm setting up the database things at the moment so I'll let you know